# Passing Eval from ASPX to Javascript function as Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

```
<a id="lblShowTimings"
     runat="server"
     title='<%# Eval("SHOW_Name") %>'
     onclick='PopulateTicketDiv(<%#Eval("SHOW_ID") %>)'>  <-- this is the problem
  %#Eval("SHOW_Time") %>
</a>
```

Can Eval be passed as an argument to a javascript function?
If so whats the syntax?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes.  What you want to do is this, though:

```
onclick='<%# "PopulateTicketDiv(" +Eval("SHOW_ID") + " );" %>'
```

Answer (score 22):

The above solution creates problem when you want to pass the string as parameter,
you can use following syntax to get through:

```
OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("javascript:return displayDeleteWarning(\"{0}\")", Eval("ItemName").ToString()) %>'
```

Above line should work irrespective of parameter data type

Comment: `OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("javascript:return displayDeleteWarning(\"{0}\")", Eval("ItemName").ToString()) %>'` of Rohan's post is helpful in a situation where you want to pass 'Eval' value to javascript function as parameter. You can also pass multilple 'Eval' values as parameter.

Comment: Yes the accepted solution make an error in client-side.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
<script type="javascript">
     //Pollute the global namespace
     var ticketDivID = <%= SHOW_ID %>
</script>

<a id="lblShowTimings" runat="server" title='<%# Eval("SHOW_Name") %>' onclick='PopulateTicketDiv(ticketDivID)'> <%#Eval("SHOW_Time") %></a>
```

On a side note because you've got runat="server" you can set the onclick from the backend in OnRowDataBound if this is in a grid/repeater or on page_load if not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this syntax within a gridview, repeater or..etc.

```
<asp:ImageButton  
 ID="Imagebutton1" runat="server"
 ImageUrl="../../common/images/pencil.gif"                
 OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("EditBankAccount(\"{0}\");", Eval("BankAccountID")) %>'
 OnClick="ImgBankAccountsDGEdit_Click"/>
```

Your JavaScript function would be:

```
 function EditBankAccount(bankaccountid) {
       // Your code goes here
       // return true OR false based on your requirement
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pls Check this code

onclick='<%#Eval("DocumentPath","Chk(\"{0}\")") %>'

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to escape the quote

```
<asp:CheckBox onclick='<%# "ToggleByPassValidationRules(" + "\"" + Eval("Name") + "\"" + ");" %>' ID="chkIsRuleActive" runat="server" Enabled="false" />
```