# Passing JavaScript parameters through ASP.NET ListView

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to pass parameters to a JavaScript function from a link button in a ListView the function only alerts the the passed parameters so I used Eval("Value") as my parameter but it seems that I'm making a mistake.

My code for passing the parameter is

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="hello(<%#string.Concat(Eval("Longitude"),",",Eval("Latitude")) %>);">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

and the alert function is very simple

```
 function hello(x){
    alert(x);
}
```

and the server tag is still not well formed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should use single-quotes `'` instead of double-quotes `"` when a property contains server-code.

```
<asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" OnClientClick='<%#Eval("Foo")%>' />
```

Comment: @Islam also try to surround the parameters for the JavaScript-function with quotes: `hello("<%#Eval("")%>")`. You should really use a JavaScript-console to debug. At least check the source of the page to make sure the HTML is well formed.

Comment: I'm sure that the HTML isn't well formed, but I cannot figure the problem so I posted my code to discuss it.

Comment: @Islam If the code compiles, you should be able to find the problem through a JavaScript-console.

Comment: It is fine, the solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249926/passing-eval-from-aspx-to-javascript-function-as-parameter

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, but, it looks like the binding mechanism is confused. I have struggled with this before and came up with the following work-around.

1. Add a method to your code behind page.

   protected string CreateJavascriptCall(object longitude, object latitude)
   {
       return String.Format("hello({0},{1});return false;", longitude, latitude);
   }
2. Change your aspx page code to:

   asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick='<%#CreateJavascriptCall(Eval("Longitude"), Eval("Latitude"))%>'>LinkButton