# ASPX <%# EVAL %> in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, eval

Trying to implement a jQuery Corner Page Peel at: [Big Bike Parts, Inc.](http://www.bigbikeparts.com/templates/product.aspx?ProductGuid=17-964&GroupGuid=16)

Currently our website is integrated with our Inventory Management System, and all of the information displayed on the website, is actually stored in our Microsoft Dynamics SQL database.

We have the ability to add a variety of images to our product pages, and have done so using the following code elements:

product.vb

```
'PROMO IMAGE
    Public ReadOnly Property PROMOIMG() As String
        Get
            Return m_dictData("PROMOIMG")
        End Get
    End Property
```

product.aspx

```
<div class="ProductTemplate_Promo">
<img src="<%=Vroot %>/<%# Eval("PROMOIMG")%>" />
</div>
```

This has worked well for allowing us to set the path to the Image inside our Inventory Management system, and have a single line of code to pull all different images for the product page.

I would like to incorporate this into a jQuery script on the same page, for instance:

```
    <script src="<%=Vroot %>/script/pagepeel/jquery.peelback.js"></script>

<%-- PAGE PEEL IMAGE --%>
<%If (m_dictProductDict.Exists("PROMOIMG")) Then%>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('body').peelback({
    adImage  : '<%=Vroot %>/<%# Eval("PROMOIMG")%>',
    peelImage  : '<%=Vroot %>/script/pagepeel/assets/peel-image.png',
    clickURL : 'http://www.bigbikeparts.com/',
    smallSize: 50,
    bigSize: 500,
    gaTrack  : true,
    gaLabel  : 'Big Bike Parts',
    autoAnimate: true
  });
});
</script>
```

This code works in practice, in that it only shows this page peel effect on products that have an image identified in the PROMOIMG field in our Inventory System. However, the `<%# Eval("PROMOIMG")%>` does not appear to work inside the `<script>` tag.

Is there an alternative solution for accessing this variable? We have resorted to using `<%=Vroot %>/script/pagepeel/demo/peel-ad.png` however this does not allow us to make variations of the page peel for different parts.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= someValue %>
```

instead of

```
<%# Eval("PROMOIMG")%>
```

Regarding

```
'someValue'
```

Which you present as `Eval("PROMOIMG")` in your sample code since your code is not part of the Grid or Repeater you will need to get this from either a control directly, session, viewstate or server side variable. Your code sample does not allow me to understand where is the original source of this value.

To see this at work add this in your code behind:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    public string someValue = "Hello World";
```

Comment: To be honest, I'm fairly inexperienced in coding. I can do basic copy/paste and duplicate code/modify it for my needs.

Where the values come from, is our SQL inventory database. In simple terms, I have an item card, with a model number, and a column to enter a path for and image, such that select parts will have a value in the PROMOIMG column of the SQL database.

The ONLY lines of code needed to read this value is by inserting:

`Public ReadOnly Property PROMOIMG() As String
        Get
            Return m_dictData("PROMOIMG")
        End Get
    End Property`

into product.vb file

Comment: I can then call that property using: `<%# Eval("PROMOIMG")%>` in the product.aspx file

Comment: If PROMOIMG is property of the page you do not need EVAL function just use PROMOIMG in the same way I used someValue

Comment: So doing that returned: Compiler Error Message: BC30451: Name 'PROMOIMG' is not declared.

I guess my lack of understanding is with how to declare a property. In my mind I can enter: `<img src="<%=Vroot %>/<%# Eval("PROMOIMG")%>" />` and it will show the img, but go one line down and put it in a `<script>` and the same `<%=Vroot %>/<%# Eval("PROMOIMG")%>` does not work. It doesn't make sense to me. Where would I need to define this value? And would this new definition need to be worked all the way backwards to call from the SQL, or can it somehow grab from the already defined value in the .vb?

Comment: @TheMrMystery please note that variable someValue is declared on the page class. So needs to your PROMOIMG variable

Comment: I will have to search for it. This was an integrated web package we have spent the last 6 months getting up and running, and these cosmetic/functional changes, are something we are attempting to learn/do ourselves. There are about 1,800 total files, not counting pictures. I'm not sure where this page class is. I'll do some digging and see where to add this.

Comment: The accepted answer looks like bad advice, not knowing how to work with Eval...  can anybody in the know confirm?

Comment: @pashute at least tell us why you think it is bad advice, if it works and there is no down side of using this solution

Comment: Because the question was: Why the Eval is giving him an error inside the script, while working in the html. Instead of answering it, you sidestepped. 

Here's the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249926/passing-eval-from-aspx-to-javascript-function-as-parameter