# How to pass bind or eval arguments with the client function 「OnClientClicking」?

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnbSeach" CssClass="BtnSearch" runat="server" Text="Seach" OnClientClick='window.open("ItemSeach.aspx?ItemID=123", "_blank")' />
```

How replace `123` Change to `'<%# Eval("FileCode")) %>'`

Comment: You can not change 'window.open("ItemSeach.aspx?ItemID=123", "_blank")' here for that you have to call function like function(event data){} and call that function event onClientClick=data('<%# Eval("FileCode")) %>')

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Eval from ASPX to Javascript function as Parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249926/passing-eval-from-aspx-to-javascript-function-as-parameter)

Comment: onClientClick=data('<%# Eval("FileCode")) %>')  F5 →  Error

Comment: Tried a combination of many ineffective, Look liks go back to Server  → Use  → ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ALERT", "window.open('" + urlOpen + ",'Intro');", true);

Comment: Formatting content highlights

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnbSeach" CssClass="BtnSearch" runat="server" Text="Seach" OnClientClick='window.open("ItemSeach.aspx?ItemID="+ Eval("FileCode") + "", "_blank")' />
```

or

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnbSeach" CssClass="BtnSearch" runat="server" Text="Seach" OnClientClick='<%# Eval("FileCode","window.open('ItemSeach.aspx?ItemID={0}', '_blank') %>' />
```

Comment: 1. 0x800a1391 - JavaScript ~~~~ 'Eval' undefined  T.T

Comment: 2. "window.open('ItemSeach.aspx?ItemID={0}', '_blank')"  ?  F5 → Error  T.T