# Pass JSON string into clientside onclick event from EVAL

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

On the UI, I've got this:

[image]

It's a div inside a Gridview with a JSON string inside of it, and next to it is an icon that I want to use as a "copy to clipboard".  I already have the CopyToClipBoard javascript method, and it works fine.  What I'm having trouble with is getting the json string inside of the onclick method.  Some things I've tried:

```
onclick='copyToClipboard("<%# Eval("LogText")%>")'
onclick="copyToClipboard('<%# Eval("LogText")%>')"
```

And all of the suggestions on this thread:

[Passing Eval from ASPX to Javascript function as Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249926/passing-eval-from-aspx-to-javascript-function-as-parameter)

Here's the full JSON string:

```
{
  "DoorId": "11574544",
  "DoorName": "out - door controller",
  "CardNumber": "65529",
  "FacilityCode": null,
  "EventID": "570924d6-94b4-45b4-aa2d-9ab4075dc668",
  "EventTimestamp": "2017-11-10 11:10:10.301",
  "Name": "Norman Bates",
  "AccessControlUserId": "15531926",
  "OrganizationSys": 1012,
  "AccessGranted": true,
  "FirstName": "Norman",
  "LastName": "Bates",
  "Email": null,
  "UserName": "normanbates",
  "Password": "Password",
  "Pin": null,
  "CreateUserIfNotExists": false,
  "CreateDoorIfNotExists": true,
  "DoorStatusSys": 476,
  "DoorLocationSys": 103979,
  "AccessIntegrationSys": 100001
}
```

The problem is that all of the quotes seem to be messing things up. At least I think. For example, with this:

```
onclick='copyToClipboard("<%# Eval("LogText")%>")'
```

I get this:

```
<img src="..." onclick="copyToClipboard("{"DoorId":"11574544","DoorName":"out - door controller","CardNumber":"65529","FacilityCode":null,"EventID":"570924d6-94b4-45b4-aa2d-9ab4075dc668","EventTimestamp":"2017-11-10 11:10:10.301","Name":"Norman Bates","AccessControlUserId":"15531926","OrganizationSys":1012,"AccessGranted":true,"FirstName":"Norman","LastName":"Bates","Email":null,"UserName":"normanbates","Password":"Password","Pin":null,"CreateUserIfNotExists":false,"CreateDoorIfNotExists":true,"DoorStatusSys":476,"DoorLocationSys":103979,"AccessIntegrationSys":100001}")">
```

When I click on the icon, I get this in the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Not sure how to get this right.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered storing your json inside a javascript variable and then just writting a variable name inside that onclick event? I have had success with this, i have had to javascript serialize my json before.

Infact if it is a global variable you will not have to pass it as a parameter but can already access it on the page. why dont you drop and parse your json object on the page load as a global variable and then you can access is from anywhere.

e.g.

```
<asp:literal runat="server" ID="litJsonBlob" />  
<img src="..." onclick="doSomething(jsonBlob)" />
```

code behind

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(LogText);

litJsonBlob.Text = string.Format("<script>var jsonBlob = JSON.parse('{0}')</script>")", serializedResult)
```

alternively drop your LogText straigt in the variable i dont know exactly what your set up is:

```
<script> var jsonBlob = JSON.parse('<%# Eval("LogText")%>'); </script>
<img src="..." onclick="doSomething(jsonBlob)" />
```

By the way i dont know where that json string come from but if you do drop it inside the literal control remember that it is vulnerable to javascript injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the quotes in your json string with "

```
Eval("LogText").Replace("\"","&quot;")
```