# How to pass Eval arguments as parameters in javascript function from a button in GridView

Tags: javascript, asp.net

'Im pretty new in asp.net webforms
and i came across this problem where I want to pass eval arguments as parameters in javascript and it somehow does not provoke the javascript function'

C#

```
 <asp:GridView ID="CustomerOrderGrid" CssClass="Gridview" runat="server"
    Width="100%">
         <Columns>
           <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-BackColor="#bee3f1" ItemStyle-CssClass="text-left CustomerGrid 
           OrderGridRow" ItemStyle-Width="150px"  
                HeaderText="ORDER DATA">
           <ItemTemplate >
              <p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" 
           onclick='<%# "ShowOrderDetails(" +Eval("OrderCode") + "," +Eval("CustomerName") + "," +Eval("CustomerMobileNumber") + " );" %>' >View Details
    </button>
              </p>
              </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
              </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Javascript

```
function ShowOrderDetails(OrderCode, CustomerName, CustomerMobile)
{
    alert(OrderCode);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Eval from ASPX to Javascript function as Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249926/passing-eval-from-aspx-to-javascript-function-as-parameter)

Comment: I saw this and also followed it but sadly didnt work

Comment: what javascript error you are getting

Comment: you will require to pass the function parameters in double quotes. try to use `String.Format` in the example.

Comment: Yes Brother your second solution worked
the format of the string that I used was not correct
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try something like below should work

```
 onclick='<%# String.Format("ShowOrderDetails(\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\")",Eval("OrderCode"),Eval("CustomerName"),Eval("CustomerMobileNumber"))%>'
```